# How can I lock a transition in CSS according to the value I select from a <select>?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move a label on a form with CSS, when focus on the `<select>` and select a different option than the first one, the problem is that when I select a different option than the first one the label goes back to its original position but I want it to lock in the previous position if the user chose a different option, but it is overlapping just like this:

[image: Problem]

This is the code I have, thanks

CSS:

```
select:not([value='opt1']),
select:focus ~ label{
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-field">
     <select id="coutry" name="country" placeholder=" ">
          <option value="opt1"> </option>
          <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
          <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
          <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
          <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
          <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
          <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
          <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
          <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
     </select>
     <label for="f4">Country/Region</label>
</div>
```

FULL CSS code:

```
.group
{
    width: 76%;
    height: 23rem;
    color: white;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0rem 8rem;
    padding: 2rem 2rem;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    /*background: green;*/
}

.title
{
    float: left;
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    padding: 7rem 1.5rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    width: 40%;
    /*background: hotpink;*/
}

.content
{
    float: left;
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    padding: 6rem 1.5rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 40%;
    /*background: red;*/
}

.content #contact
{
    float: left;
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    padding: -8rem -3rem;
    margin: -5rem 0rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    /*background: red;*/
}

/*  FORM   */

form
{
    /*background: black;*/
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.form-field {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.form-field:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

form input, 
form textarea,
form select,
form button
{
    display: block;
    padding: 0rem 0.75rem;
    margin: 2.5rem 0.25rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
}

label {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.8rem;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0.2rem;
    text-align: left;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.2s 0.3s;
}

label span {
    width: 20rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    transition: opacity 0.5s 0s;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 2.7rem;
}

input {
        width: 20rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

input:hover,
input:focus,
input:active {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ECF87F;
  outline: none;
  /*   border-radius: 5px; */
}

input:disabled:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label,
textarea:focus ~ label {
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown):focus ~ label span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s;
}


select:not([value='opt1']),
select:focus ~ label{
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

select {
        width: 21.5rem;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  height: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

textarea
{
    background: transparent;
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    width: 20rem;
    height: 5rem;
}

button{
    width: 6rem;
    height: 10rem;
    background: #59981A;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Your `select:not([value='opt1']), select:focus ~ label` select all elements that either match `select:not([value='opt1'])` or `select:focus ~ label`.

Comment: Both, what I'm trying to do is to move -25px up whenever the value of the selected element is different from 'opt1' and also when it is in focus, but I don't really know if this is right at all.

Comment: Is JavaScript solution OK for you?

Comment: Can you please share full css and HTML

Comment: Sure, I'll add it now

Comment: I know there are easier ways with JavaScript, but I wanted to try it with CSS only.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use `select[value]`. It must be `option[value]`. But then you can't use `option[value] ~ label` because `label` is in a different level. So I don't see any way to achieve the desired result with CSS only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think JavaScript is necessary in this case because `option[value]` must be used instead of `select[value]`, which does not allow you to target `label` in CSS (it's in the parent level). A very similar option to what you already have is this: add `onchange = "this.dataset.value = this.value"` to your select and change `select:not([value='opt1'])` to `select:not([data-value='opt1']) ~ label`. Like that:

CSS

```
select:not([data-value='opt1']) ~ label,
select:focus ~ label{
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-field">
     <select id="coutry" name="country" placeholder=" " onchange="this.dataset.value = this.value">
          <option value="opt1"> </option>
          <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
          <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
          <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
          <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
          <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
          <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
          <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
          <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
     </select>
     <label for="f4">Country/Region</label>
</div>
```

So it's the same idea like you have in your CSS, but data-value is targeted instead of value.

Comment: Glad to be of help